# npm run build elifecycle error code - can't figure out the issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-redux, npm-start

I'm building my first website and started with a react template from someone else. To develop locally on my Windows computer I used "npm start" which was fine. Now I'm trying to deploy on my Linux machine but I'm just getting a white page and my react js files are not loading.

I'm now trying with "npm run build" which is launching the production config (which I didn't write) and it's throwing an error I can't figure out. Below is all the relevant info I have. Does anyone have ANY idea what it could be? I've wasted hours and hours trying to figure this out.

I tried updating npm, reinstalling node modules, using admin mode and so on. The problem happens on both my windows and Linux machine when using "npm run build".

Any suggestions, please?

### Command line error on LINUX

```
ERROR in bundle2.js from UglifyJs
Invalid assignment [bundle2.js:15571,30]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js?sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?outputStyle=expanded!app/styles/index.scss:
   [0] ./node_modules/css-loader?sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?outputStyle=expanded!./app/styles/index.scss 2.86 kB {0} [built]
        factory:13ms building:8255ms = 8268ms
    + 1 hidden module

npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.14.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! cb-react-redux@0.1.0 build: `webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors`
 npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cb-react-redux@0.1.0 build script 'webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the cb-react-redux package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs cb-react-redux
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls cb-react-redux
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/psmet/piettest/npm-debug.log
```

### Debug log file from WINDOWS

```
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   
'C:\\Users\\psmet\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm- 
cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle cb-react-redux@0.1.0~prebuild: cb-react-redux@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle cb-react-redux@0.1.0~build: cb-react-redux@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle cb-react-redux@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle cb-react-redux@0.1.0~build: PATH: 
C:\Users\psmet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm- 
lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\psmet\Documents\GUI\trackingcodes\node_modules\.bin;c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\SysWow64;C:\Users\psmet\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\psmet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\psmet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\psmet\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle cb-react-redux@0.1.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\psmet\Documents\GUI\trackingcodes
10 silly lifecycle cb-react-redux@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors' ]
11 silly lifecycle cb-react-redux@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle cb-react-redux@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: cb-react-redux@0.1.0 build: `webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\psmet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\psmet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid cb-react-redux@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\psmet\Documents\GUI\trackingcodes
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\psmet\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.9.4
19 verbose npm  v6.1.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error cb-react-redux@0.1.0 build: `webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors`
```

### webpack.production.config.js (both linux/windows)

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var loaders = require('./webpack.loaders');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var WebpackCleanupPlugin = require('webpack-cleanup-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

loaders.push({
 test: /\.scss$/,
 loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', use : 'css-loader?sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded'}),
 exclude: ['node_modules']
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
   './app/src/index.jsx',
    './app/styles/index.scss'
  ],
output: {
   publicPath: './',        
   path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
   filename: 'bundle2.js'
},
resolve: {
   extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
},
module: {
   loaders
},
plugins: [
  new WebpackCleanupPlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
       NODE_ENV: '"production"'
   }
  }),
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false,
    screw_ie8: true,
    drop_console: true,
    drop_debugger: true
  }
}),
new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'style.css',
  allChunks: true
 }),
]
};
```

### package.json (both win/linux)

```
{
 "name": "cb-react-redux",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "description": "React Webpack Babel Starter Kit",
 "main": "''",
 "scripts": {
   "build": "webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors",
   "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --profile --colors",
   "lint": "eslint --ext js --ext jsx app || exit 0",
   "prod": "node server.js",
   "dev": " webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server",
   "test": "export NODE_ENV=test && jest"
 },
 "repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "https://github.com/alicoding/react-webpack-babel"
    },
 "author": "Rick Ekins",
 "license": "MIT",
 "homepage": "https://github.com/alicoding/react-webpack-babel#readme",
 "dependencies": {
   "axios": "^0.18.0",
   "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
   "ejs": "^2.5.7",
   "express": "^4.16.2",
   "http": "0.0.0",
   "material-ui": "^0.19.4",
   "mysql": "^2.15.0",
   "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
   "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
   "npm": "^6.1.0",
   "query-string": "^6.1.0",
   "react": "^16.2.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
   "react-ga": "^2.4.1",
   "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha.4",
   "redux": "^3.7.2",
   "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
   "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
   "serve-favicon": "^2.4.5",
   "serve-static": "^1.13.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
   "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
   "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
   "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
   "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.0.0",
   "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
   "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
   "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
   "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
   "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
   "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
   "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
   "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
   "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
   "eslint": "^4.11.0",
   "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.3.2",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
   "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
   "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
   "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "loglevel": "^1.6.0",
   "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
   "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "*",
   "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
     "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
   "webpack": "^3.8.1",
   "webpack-cleanup-plugin": "^0.5.1",
   "webpack-dashboard": "^1.0.2",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
 },
 "jest": {
   "verbose": true,
    "bail": true,
   "collectCoverage": true,
   "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
   "moduleNameMapper": {
     "\\.(jpe?g|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff2?|mp[34]|webm|wav|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
     "\\.(css|less|s[ac]ss|styl)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
   },
   "moduleFileExtensions": [
     "js",
     "jsx"
   ],
   "moduleDirectories": [
     "node_modules"
   ]
 }
```

}

### And here is my webpack.config.js (both win/linux)

```
"use strict";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var loaders = require('./webpack.loaders');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const HOST = process.env.HOST || "127.0.0.1";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || "8888";

loaders.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?importLoaders=1', 'sass-loader'],
  exclude: ['node_modules']
});

module.exports = {
   entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
     './app/src/index.jsx', // your app's entry point
  ],
   devtool: process.env.WEBPACK_DEVTOOL || 'eval-source-map',
  output: {
   publicPath: '/',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
   filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
 },
 module: {
    loaders
 },
 devServer: {
    contentBase: "./public",
    // do not print bundle build stats
    noInfo: true,
    // enable HMR
   hot: true,
    // embed the webpack-dev-server runtime into the bundle
   inline: true,
   // serve index.html in place of 404 responses to allow HTML5 history
   historyApiFallback: true,
   port: PORT,
   host: HOST
 },
   plugins: [
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css',
        allChunks: true
      }),
      new DashboardPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './app/src/template.html',
     files: {
       css: ['style.css'],
       js: [ "bundle.js"],
     }
   }),
  ]
};
```

Comment: Which node version are you using? Because I can see from the first error log node v6 and npm3. And from the second log, I can see node8 and npm6.

Comment: And please double check with permissions too.

Comment: On windows: npm v6.1 and node v8.9.4

On Linux: npm 3.10 and node v6.14

I edited the post to show which error was from linux and which one from windows. Both of them are throwing the lifecycle error and using the same config files. I'm hoping one solution will work for both.